# initial conditions after substitution

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, hyperbolic-equations

I'm stuck with the following initial value problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(t,x,y) &= \Delta_{x,y} \int_y^\infty u(t,x,\eta) \, d\eta \\ u(0,x,y) &= u_0(x,y)
\end{aligned}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
After substituting
\begin{equation*}
w(t,x,y) = \int_y^\infty u(t,x,\eta) \, d\eta
\end{equation*}
I get
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t \partial y} w + \Delta_{x,y} w &=  0 \\
w(0,x,y) &= \int_y^\infty u_0(x,\eta) \, d\eta
\end{aligned}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
With the change of variables
\begin{align*}
t' &= x \\
x' &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8 (\sqrt{2}-1})} \cdot \left( (2-\sqrt{2}) \cdot y -t \right) \\
y' &=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{8 (\sqrt{2}+1})} \cdot \left((2+\sqrt{2}) \cdot y -t\right)
\end{align*}
(2) becomes for $w=w(t',x',y')$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x'^2} w = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t'^2} w + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y'^2} w \tag{3}
\end{equation}

For given initials $w(t',0,y')$ and $\partial_{x'}w(t',0,y')$, Polyanin (2002, Handbook of Linear Partial Differential Equations for Engineers and Scientists) gives an explicit solution of (3).

However I can't seem to see a way to connect my original initial conditions in (1) / (2) at $t=0$ to those required at $x'=0$... Is there a way?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, but I was a little confused from the wording of your question. Just to make sure, you're asking how the initial conditions $w(t', 0, y'), \partial_{x'} w(t', 0, y')$ came from your original initial condition, $u(0, x, y) = u_{0}(x, y)$?

Comment: Yes, I think we mean the same thing. I am wondering if there is a way to know $w(t',0,y')$ and $\partial_{x'}w(t',0,y')$ in order to solve (3).
All I see is that $x'=0$ means $(2-\sqrt{2})y = t$, and I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: On what page does Polyanin provide the solution? I've got the book, it might help if I look at the problem.

Comment: 343 in my edition. Section 5.1.1-2., Cauchy problem of the wave equation with two space variables.